# Dependency error when install ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

When I try to install ggplot with this code

```
install.packages("png")
install.packages("RgoogleMaps")
install.packages("ggmap")
library(ggmap)
```

It returns error

```
installing to /usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.2/lib/R/library/00LOCK-png/00new/png/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘png’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.2/lib/R/library/00LOCK-png/00new/png/libs/png.so':
  dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.2/lib/R/library/00LOCK-png/00new/png/libs/png.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libz.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.2/lib/R/library/00LOCK-png/00new/png/libs/png.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.2/lib/R/library/png’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘png’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘png’ is not available for package ‘RgoogleMaps’
* removing ‘/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.2/lib/R/library/RgoogleMaps’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RgoogleMaps’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘RgoogleMaps’, ‘png’ are not available for package ‘ggmap’
* removing ‘/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.2/lib/R/library/ggmap’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggmap’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/fd/7vyffy191_l3j6fhyqbvsn0r0000gn/T/RtmptKSXHF/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Error in library(ggmap) : there is no package called ‘ggmap’
```

I am installing all the dependencies that the error says are missing. By adding the install packages before installing the ggmap itself.

Comment: Are you on a mac? Did you install R via brew? Is there any reason you aren't using the official R release? Normally these linking problems don't exist when you use the official distributions.

Comment: Yes, I am on a mac, I'll try to do that! Thank you!